# Facebooker-rails3 installation problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebooker

I am trying to install facebooker-rails3 plugin like this

rails plugin install git://github.com/kulbirsaini/facebooker-rails3.git

it does install in it vendor directory but it doesnt create facebooker.yml
 should it create it all?
if not thn where should i configure facebook settings?

Thanks

Comment: On a side note, Facebooker is deprecated, you should consider using Facebooker 2.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin adds some useful tasks to rake.
you should run the rake task command on the console on the rails project directory:

```
rake facebooker:setup
```

After that the facebooker.yml is created and is pretty straight forward to complete.

Hope you find it useful.

Greetings!